# Line $y=c$ where $c$ is a constant intersects $y=x^2$ with part of it reflected at $y=1$ at $A, B, C, D$ where $AB=BC=CD$. What is $AB$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

> An M-shaped curve is created by graphing the parabola $y=x^2$ in the coordinate plane, and then reflecting the part of the parabola that is above the line $y=1$ across the line $y=1$. There is a horizontal line that intersects the M-shaped curve at four points $A, B, C$, and $D$ so that $AB=BC=CD$. As a fraction in simplest radical form, what is the distance $\overline{AB}$?

I begin by drawing a diagram:[image]

The M-shaped curve is traced in red, and the four yellow dots represent A, B, C, D, from left to right, respectively.

I find the reflected parabola's equation to be $y=-x^2+2$ because it is a parabola opening downward shifted 2 up.

So I can say for $|x|\le1$, $y=x^2$; for $|x|\ge1$, $y=-x^2+2$. So it's a piecewise function.

I am stuck here. I assume I need to find solutions for $x$ from both parabola's equations, but I am not sure how. Help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Max0815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** I would consider finding a straight line
$$r : y = k$$
with $0<k<1$, such that the intersection between $r_1$ and
$$\gamma_1 : y=x^2$$
generates a chord of some length $L$ and the intersection between $r$ and 
$$\gamma_2:y =-x^2+2$$ 
generates a chord of length $3L$.

Intersecting $r$ and $\gamma_1$ yields
$$
\begin{cases}
y = k\\
y=x^2
\end{cases}
$$
and thus the chord lenght is
$$L = 2\sqrt{k}.$$
Similarly, by the intersection between $r$ and $\gamma_2$ you get
$$3L = 2\sqrt{2-k}.$$
Equating the last two expressions and solving for $k$ will bring you close to your final result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't fully understand how you got r:y=k and what your variables mean. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @Max0815 let me ask you, instead, a question. Suppose to "reverse" the problem. Had you been given the equation of an horizonal line, say $y=2/3$, would you be able to find the length of the segments? How would you proceed in that case?

Comment: I would set $y=x^2$ equal to 2/3 for points A and D and set $y=2-x^2$ equal to 2/3 for points B and C.

Comment: Ahah! I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let the line that intersects the M-shaped curve to give points $A, B, C$ and $D$ be $y=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

We can see that points $A$ and $D$ are part of the parabola $y=-x^2+2$.
We can also see points $B$ and $C$ are part of the parabola $y=x^2$.

We can set equations now: $$c=-x^2+2$$$$\implies2-c=x^2$$$$\implies x=\pm\sqrt{2-c}$$

Thus, we can see that point $A$(the least greatest) has $x$ coordinate of $-\sqrt{2-c}$ and $D$(the greatest) has $x$ coordinate of $\sqrt{2-c}$.

$$c=x^2$$$$\implies x=\pm\sqrt{c}$$

Thus, we can see that point $B$(second to last least greatest) has $x$ coordinate of $-\sqrt{c}$ and point $C$ has $x$ coordinate of $\sqrt{c}$.

So, generalizing, we have $$A=-\sqrt{2-c}$$$$B=-\sqrt{c}$$$$C=\sqrt{c}$$$$D=\sqrt{2-c}$$

Now, we can set equations and solve for $c$. In order to avoid getting an equation with unlimited solutions, we put the "$\sqrt{c}$"s on one side, and the "$\sqrt{2-c}$"s on the other.

We can see that $$D-A=3(C-B)$$

Thus, $$\implies\sqrt{2-c}--\sqrt{2-c}=3(\sqrt{c}--\sqrt{c})$$$$\implies2\sqrt{2-c}=6\sqrt{c}$$$$\implies\sqrt{2-c}=3\sqrt{c}$$$$\implies 2-c=9c$$$$\implies 10c=2$$$$\implies c=\frac{1}{5}$$

Since we are trying to find the distance between two points, we will find the distance between points $C$ and $B$ and that will be our answer:

$$C-B=\text{answer}$$$$\implies 2\sqrt{c}=\text{answer}$$$$\implies 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}=\text{answer}$$$$\implies \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}=\text{answer}$$$$\implies \boxed{\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}}$$